# How to install cdc_acm version driver ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tty, cdc

I have a USB Serial Scanner device working using cdc_acm 1-1.2:1.0 driver, but I have another PC with the same ubuntu version (16.04), in this PC the scanner not working, it uses cdc_acm 3-3:1.0, how I can install or compile cdc_acm 1-1.2:1.0  version driver?